# Should I merge the spark output files?

Tags: apache-spark

Apache Spark usually output part-00XXX files. Is the best practice to merge them or to leave them as is on the storage? (I am using google cloud storage)

Comment: What do you want to do with the output files when they're ready?

Comment: Probably further Spark processing.

Comment: If that's the case, I'd say leave them as-is. It doesn't hurt, and Spark will write them out and read them in parallel.

Comment: In addition that merging files in Cloud Storage would not be a wise idea to merge files that will need further processing.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that is a choice but I would say no because:

- if you do computation over big data files merging will not be easy because you will obtain a huge file
- the different file can correspond to the RDD partition so you can take advantage of it for further processing (like a sort of filtering just reading  some files and not all of them )
- further processing of the data is easy with spark because .textfile accept wildcard as * to read all text file in a folder so no need to merge them

Hope this answer your question

Answer (score 0):

I would say that merging breaks the propice of distributed computing. You may have to read from the same file heading to concurrency issues.

But if you want to perform a quick analysis, with say Python's Pandas try this:

```
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration
import org.apache.hadoop.fs._

def merge(srcPath: String, dstPath: String): Unit =  {
  val hadoopConfig = new Configuration()
  val hdfs = FileSystem.get(hadoopConfig)
  FileUtil.copyMerge(hdfs, new Path(srcPath), hdfs, new Path(dstPath), false, hadoopConfig, null)
}
```